# How to use pipeline parameters in DF Data Flow, Dataset source options

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I've been at this for a day now, trying every variation possible and searching for others solutions. I have a DF pipeline with a few DataBricks notebooks with the end result being saved to blob storage, but needs to be joined with a SQL table in order to update some values. I am using dynamic folder names to pull the blob file which works fine, but when I try the same thing for my SQL query, it doesn't fail, but it doesn't seem to select any records. So how does one use pipeline parameters in a Data Flow SQL query?

Overview of the pipeline:[image]

The failing source:[image]

My query to use the variable:
[image]

Finally the results:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to create a data flow parameter, then pass the pipeline parameter to data flow parameter, using data flow parameter in the SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

The Azure SQL database source dataset doesn't work in data flow.

You need to create a pipeline paremeter a data flow parameter, use data flow parameter in the query.

For example:

**Create the data flow parameter:**
[image]

**Query option:**

```
concat('select * from ', $Category)
```

[image]

**Pipeline parameter:**
[image]

**Set the Data Flow parameter value from pipeline**:
[image]

Comment: Hi! and thank you for answering, but following your directions, it fails with an error of invalid PsuedoColumn. Your dataset source query options page looks different then mine so idk if things have changed since. I also attempted to use the string interpolation method my screen says to use. Which looks like this '{$Category}', but that throws an invalid syntax error. If I check the box to use the parameter as an expression it still errors, but it knows what parameter I passed in because it fails with this error missing '=' at 'Vinegar'. With my string being Apple Cider Vinegar.

Comment: @Voxum I use windows Data Factory V2 UI.  `$Category` to get the parameter and `'{$Category}` is invalid. Please don't use quote for the parameter.

Comment: How do you specify a simple query like this in Expression builder? SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'Y'? I have tried 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = ' + toString('Y') but it keeps saying its "Invalid Column 'Y' " when I view it in Data Preview.